# How i can pass the id of element to Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

So I took data from my server. Than I built **listView**. On click on element i wan't to load new activity. So i need to get the id of element and send it to my server. How i can do it? is it possible to set some proprety = id_element when i create ListView? 
So my code when i create list view"

```
this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   InboxActivity.this,
                   R.layout.da_item,
                   emails
                  );
this.ll.setAdapter(this.adapter);
```

How i can to get id of selected element in the method onClick ?

```
            So how i build **listView**

            i do this code to build my listView



                List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);                         
                        emails.add(json_data.getString("mittente"));
                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            The data which i take from server it is json array like

            [0][id] = 1;
            [0][mitente] = my@email.ocm
            [1][id] = 2;
            [1][mitente] = my@emaasdil.ocm

            How i can to pass in my listview id of element and than when i click to element get this id ?
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: what are those ids you are talking about? are those the strings that you are using to fill up your `ListView`?

Comment: Implement onItemClick method of ListView.

Comment: blackbelt, i take array from server like this

`
array[0] =>[id] = 1
array[0] =>[email] = someemail@sd.com
array[1] =>[id] = 2
array[1] =>[email] = som23il@sd.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement list `setOnItemClickListener` like:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

            System.out.println("Selected Email ID:::::" + emails[position));

        }

    });
```

Comment: "On click on element i wan't to load new activity". he already mentioned that.

Comment: YEs but see please how i built listView

Comment: this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                   InboxActivity.this,
                   R.layout.da_item,
                   emails
                  );
emails it is array like 
[0] => t@mail.com
[1] => t2@mail.com
Can i pass also id to adapter ?

Comment: @user3323180 what are you talk in about? i do not understand.

Comment: @user3323180 used `Custom Adapter` over here and take two `ArrayList` and when you `Click` any `ListItem` get particular id and email from particular `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

```
ll.setOnItemClickListener(Adapter<?> adapter, View view, int position,, long id){
 // here position means selected position of list item


}
```

If you are maintaining the data in Array list then you can simply get that particular Object from that array by using the position.